# UWP[Xaml] How to access elements inside Button

Tags: c#, xaml

How to change **txtPIN.Text** value in C# code behind after UserControl was initialized.

Here is XAML

```
<Button x:Name="btn_pin" Content="Change PIN" Click="button_Click" Foreground="White">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/settings/lock.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtPin" Text="Change PIN" Foreground="White" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

and C#

```
public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.btn_pin.??????????
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing it the right way, just fix your xaml (I changed the Text binding of your TextBlock):

```
<Button x:Name="btn_pin" Content="Change PIN" Click="button_Click" Foreground="White">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/images/settings/lock.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtPin" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="White" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

and every time you want to change the text, change the Content of the button like this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        btn_pin.Content = "New label";
    }
```